# Add line break in <pre> tag

Tags: css, pre

I am using this css for pre tag. It does not add line break and code is mixed. I want to add line break same as we add in writing pane by hitting enter.

```
pre {
        font-size:16px;
            overflow: auto;
        padding:10px;
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
            white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
            white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
            white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
            white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
            word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */ }
```

Comment: I don't really know what you mean, but this looks right to me: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/8FGEL/

Comment: Yes I did the same and using the same code in jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/8FGEL but it still not working. breaking codes into line.

Comment: Can you show me your website?

Comment: this is my website: http://www.webkia.com/add-pingbacks-trackbacks-column-in-wp-admin-panel/

Comment: I want it like this; http://wp-snippet.com/snippets/total-pingbacks-trackbacks-within-admin-post-columns/

Comment: The problem is not with the `pre` tag.  You're somehow removing the newlines before you even output it with the `pre` tag.  Intended?

Comment: May be it's due to some other code but I could find it. Everyone suggested the same solution which I am using at the moment but it is not giving required output.